# Java Problem- Null char prints no character on Mac OS but does print a blank space on Windows

Tags: java

im trying to make a code that deletes the spaces of a text. I have programmed this on a Mac getting as result what i needed but when running the same code on Windows it prints the null character (Ascii Code 0) as a blank space.

Aclaration: "MetodosComunes.leerTextoPorTeclado()" makes the user introduce a string and assign it to the var "textoPuro".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String textoPuro;

    char espacio = ' ';

    System.out.println("Introduzca una frase: ");

    textoPuro = MetodosComunes.leerTextoPorTeclado();

    char[] contenido = new char[textoPuro.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < textoPuro.length(); i++) {

        contenido[i] = textoPuro.charAt(i);

        if (contenido[i] == espacio) {

            contenido[i] = 0;

        }

        System.out.print(contenido[i]);

    }

}
```

If I type "How are you"...

Result on Mac OS: "Howareyou"

Result on Windows: "How are you"

In Windows it actually get inside the conditional and asign the null char to that element but it keep being a blank space.

Comment: That's not the correct way to delete a character from a string, unless you then reprint the characters one by one and skip when you encounter a `'0'`.

Comment: You can't delete a char by setting it to `0`. Even if that works somewhere, it working is the problem. You are asking for bugs with this approach, especially if you ever interface with anything that expects c style strings.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than inserting a `0`, you should just skip the character entirely:

```
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < textoPuro.length(); i++) {
    char c = textoPuro.charAt(i);

    if (c != espacio) {
        contenido[k++] = c;
    }
}

System.out.println(String.valueOf(contenido, 0, k));
```

This will put only non-space characters into the array.

Comment: You might want to add `System.out.println(String.valueOf(contenido, 0, k));` at the end (and move `k` out of loop scope), since the entire `contenido` array won’t represent the shortened string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting 0 you should shift the characters